# Get a black screen after GRUB ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Tags: 12.04, grub2, graphics

I have a sony vaio vpcca15fg laptop. I was trying to install AMD Catalyst manager on Ubuntu
because I was getting major overheating issues on ubuntu as it was turning on both my graphic cards to the max (amd radeon 6630m and intel hd 4000).

I don't think the Catalyst manager installed correctly on my machine as now am getting a black screen after grub. I am new to ubuntu and I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to enter commandline.

Then if you use a mobile broadband service, use this command to connect to the network:

```
nmcli nm wwan on && nmcli con up id 'YOUR CONNECTION NAME HERE'
```

ex : `nmcli nm wwan on && nmcli con up id 'Dialog GSM Prepaid (Kitbb)'`

Then install the Radeon display driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-radeon libdrm-radeon1 xorg-video-abi-15
```